# De-Normalizing Sum of associated objects in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a gift registry app using rails 3.0.  The app allows multiple guests to contribute towards a gift.  When displaying the gifts I need to show the amount remaining, and if the total amount has been given I needs to show the item as purchased.

For performance I want to de-normalize the sum of the total contributions, and the status of the item.

Seems simple enough, but as I tried to figure out how to put this in the model in a way that is completely encapsulated, and works in all circumstances, things got much more complicated then I expected.

I tried a few different approaches including a callback on the association between item and contribution, but ultimately ended up with a callback on the contribution object.

item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  # decimal amount

  # decimal total_contributed
  # boolean purchased
  has_many :contributions, :inverse_of => :item

  def set_total_contributed
    self.total_contributed = 0
    contributions.each do |cont|
      self.total_contributed += cont.amount
    end
    purchased = self.total_contributed >=  amount
  end
end
```

order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contributions, :inverse_of => :order, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

contribution.rb

```
class Contribution < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item, :inverse_of => :contributions
  belongs_to :order, :inverse_of => :contributions

  after_create do |cont|
    item.set_total_contributed
    item.save
  end

  after_destroy do |cont|
    item.contributions.delete(cont)
    item.set_total_contributed
    item.save
  end
end
```

This appears to work in the situations I need it to, but it doesn't feel right.

First, the fact that I have to manually update the contributions association in the destroy callback seems odd.

Also, the de-normalized values are only properly updated when objects are persisted.

So the question is, how can I do this better and what's the best practice for this kind of scenario?

Comment: in set_total contributed, you could replace your loop with `self.total_contributed = contributions.sum(&:amount)`

Comment: I can't see any issue in your code except the contribution class knows too much about the Item class. 1) I'd use an observer on Contribution 2) I'd send a message to contribution to tell it to update 3) Is it really necessary to loop all contributions for calculations purposes when you delete one?

Comment: @apneadiving Thanks for the feedback,  I appreciate the suggestion of an observer and will implement that approach.  Looping for the sum probably isn't necessary.  But I was being cautious given the uncertainty I had about how things were being persisted and when.